# SPOnline Create Document List and Modify Advanced Properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, splist

In my research and coding I can programmatically create a document library/list on 0365 SharePoint Online in this fashion:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext("Http://..."))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("UserName", "SecurePwd");

    var list = new ListCreationInformation()
    {
          Title = "My Title",
          Description = "My Desicription",
          TemplateType = asDocumentLibrary ? 101 : 100, 
          QuickLaunchOption = QuickLaunchOptions.On
    };

    ctx.Web.Lists.Add(list);

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

In the above code the advance option of `QuickLaunchOption` is a property which I can change, and do.

But there are no other advance options. Do I have to query after the `ExecuteQuery` and pull down that newly created list in `SPList` form? Or is there a better way to change advance attributes of the list during creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to execute query after `ctx.Web.Lists.Add(list);`.  Simply store the list into a variable, and change the settings you need to change.  You can do a single `ExecuteQuery();` at the end.  I wish I had some links to support this, but all I can say is that I've been able to create a list, break role inheritance and add custom role assignments all before calling `ExecuteQuery();` in the past:

```
var listCreationInformation = new ListCreationInformation
{
    Title = title,
    Description = description,
    ListTemplate = listTemplate,
    TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId,
    TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind
};
var list = web.Lists.Add(listCreationInformation);
list.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
list.RoleAssignments.Add(owners, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) {contribute});
list.RoleAssignments.Add(members, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) { contribute });
list.RoleAssignments.Add(bhtg, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) { contribute });
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: In my testing, one must also call `Update()` on the list before the `ExecuteQuery`. I was not changing any of the properties you demonstrated, so I don't know if it is a requirement for those to call update or not. Regardless thanks for the correct answer.

Comment: This is just speculation, but perhaps because my updates were done with methods, I didn't need the `list.Update()` call.  Perhaps it's only needed for property assignment.